# Counting vowels and adding 5 random letters to a string (iterative and recursive)

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, random

The assignment is to create a function that takes two arguments: a number and a string.  Check the string for vowels, if the number of vowels equals the number argument, return the string.  If not, add 5 random letters to the string, and count the vowels.  Repeat until the number of vowels in the string equal the number provided.
Example:
Funct(2, 'blue')
returns 'blue'
Funct(3, 'blue')
returns 'bluequrmb'

This needs to also be completed in the recursive form, but I cannot figure out why my iterative form doesn't work.

```
import random

def VowelCount(thestring):
    Vowels = 'aeiouAEIOU'
    Count = 0
    if type(thestring) == str:
        for char in thestring:
            if char in Vowels:
               Count += 1
        return Count
    else:
        print("Enter a string.")



def AddFive(number, astring):
    LetterPull = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    newstring = list(astring)
    NString = ''.join(str(newstring))
    VowelNum = VowelCount(NString)#calling the function VowelCount with argument 'astring'
    ToFive = 0
    number != 0 == True

    while True:
        if VowelNum < number:
            if ToFive != 5:
                y = random.choice(LetterPull)
                newstring.append(y)
                ToFive += 1
            else:
                VowelNum = VowelCount(NString)
                ToFive = 0
        else:
            print(newstring)
            break
    else:
           print("Enter a higher number.")
```

Any insight would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the 'blocking' logical error:

```
else:
    VowelNum = VowelCount(''.join(newstring)) # not VowelCount(NString)
```